# how to align label and text field horizontally in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on jQuery mobile phone. I have few problems:

First I used `data-role="fieldcontain"` and still the label and input fields are not horizontal. (not on the same line)

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/vb5jA/

```
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
    <div data-role="header" style="background: green;">
            <h1>Wbservice</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
</div>

        <label for="flip-1">Flip switch:</label>
<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
    </div>
    <!--pop up screen-->

    <!-- /content -->
    <div data-position="fixed" data-role="footer"style="background: green;">

         <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another field contain to your flip .switch if you want it horizontal

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="flip-1">Flip switch:</label>
    <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option value="on">On</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

But if I understand, you don't think the label and the first input are horizontal.  But   the labels start at the upper most part of the input fields instead of centering in the middle of them.  Thats how jQuery mobiles `field contain` works.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-text.html

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vb5jA/2/

And you can always add a top margin to your inputs if you want them centered down a bit farther e.g.

```
 margin-top: 6px;
```

Comment: @user1542984 Please mark this answer as accepted if it answered you question.  Or give some feedback if it didn't work for you.  Thanks